# How to calculate Quarterly difference and add missing Quarterly with count in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data frame like this I have to get missing Quarterly value and count between them
Same with Quarterly Missing count and fill  the data frame is

```
year    Data    Id       number
    2019Q4   57170   A     1
    2019Q3   55150   A     1
    2019Q2   51109   A     1
    2019Q1   51109   A     1
    2018Q1   57170   B     5
    2018Q4   55150   B     5
    2017Q4   51109   C     7
    2017Q2   51109   C     7
    2017Q1   51109   C     7
```

Id Start year end-year count

```
  B  2018Q2    2018Q3        2  5
  B  2017Q3    2018Q3        1  5
```

How can I achieve this using python panda

Comment: How working my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert datetimes to quarter period
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.to_period('Q')
#resample by start of months with asfreq
df1 = (df.set_index('year')
         .groupby('Id')['Id']
         .resample('Q')
         .asfreq()
         .rename('val')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Id   year  val
0   A 2019Q1    A
1   A 2019Q2    A
2   A 2019Q3    A
3   A 2019Q4    A
4   B 2018Q1    B
5   B 2018Q2  NaN
6   B 2018Q3  NaN
7   B 2018Q4    B
8   C 2017Q1    C
9   C 2017Q2    C
10  C 2017Q3  NaN
11  C 2017Q4    C
```

---

```
m = df1['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df1.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df1[~m.values].groupby(['Id', 'g'])['year']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Id  first   last  size
0  B 2018Q2 2018Q3     2
1  C 2017Q3 2017Q3     1
```

EDIT:

For new columns with same values add it to `groupby`:

```
#convert datetimes to quarter period
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year']).dt.to_period('Q')
#resample by start of months with asfreq
df1 = (df.set_index('year')
         .groupby(['Id','number'])['Id'] <- added number columns
         .resample('Q')
         .asfreq()
         .rename('val')
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
   Id  number   year  val
0   A       1 2019Q1    A
1   A       1 2019Q2    A
2   A       1 2019Q3    A
3   A       1 2019Q4    A
4   B       5 2018Q1    B
5   B       5 2018Q2  NaN
6   B       5 2018Q3  NaN
7   B       5 2018Q4    B
8   C       7 2017Q1    C
9   C       7 2017Q2    C
10  C       7 2017Q3  NaN
11  C       7 2017Q4    C
```

---

```
m = df1['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df1.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df1[~m.values].groupby(['Id', 'number', 'g'])['year']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])  <- added number columns
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Id  g  first   last  size
0  B  5 2018Q2 2018Q3     2
1  C  8 2017Q3 2017Q3     1
```

Comment: Thank you amazing solutions

Comment: if their is another column in the data frame that should also include in output how can i achieve it

Comment: @raam - Can you explain more? Because here is completely changed structure of origianl DataFrame.

Comment: I improved the question just i added one more column

Comment: @raam - So there is same number per groups?